# InfoPath 2007 field that depend on other field outcome

Tags: infopath, form

In a Web-based InfoPath 2007 form, I have 2 fields, one field is a drop-down list field and another field is a text field.

The drop-down list contain two values: 'Like' and 'Dislike'.
When the user select 'Dislike', the text field will enable the user to enter why he/she dislike. However, if the user select 'Like', the text field is disabled (It will be a empty field and does not allow user to enter any data into it)

How do I simulate the above situation in a web-based InfoPath form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create the text box
- Create the dropdown

  - Create a new choise: Value=1 | Display Name= Like
  - Create a new choise: Value=2 | Display Name= Dislike
  - Modify the default choise: Value=0 | Display Name= Select...
- Add a rule to the text box (formating rule)

  - Set a condition: Dropdown | is not equal | 2
  - Click "Disable this control"